# How to use the WebSocket readyState to display connection status in app header

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, svelte

I am creating a chat widget using svelte. I want to display the websocket is connected or not using the websocket.readyState property, the readyState values as follows

- 0- Connecting,
- 1- Open,
- 2- Closing,
- 3- Closed

the status i want to display in app header is

- connecting while state is 0
- online when state is 1
- disconnected when    state is 2

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well according this documentation you can use the events to know. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/readyState)

```html
0   CONNECTING  Socket has been created. The connection is not yet open.
1   OPEN    The connection is open and ready to communicate.
2   CLOSING The connection is in the process of closing.
3   CLOSED  The connection is closed or couldn't be opened.
```

- so when `socket = new WebSocket(url)` status is `CONNECTING`
- when `onopen = (event) => { }` status is `OPEN`
- when `onclose` or `onerror` status is `CLOSED`
- when invoking `socket.close()` status is `CLOSING`

It might be some other situation for `CLOSING` but not something I know of.

Comment: yes you are totally correct about the events but

Comment: but what i want to do is create a header which shows the status of socket connection in realtime like when the connection drops it should show connecting again and when it is connected it should show online

Comment: i Dont know why some people on stackoverflow downvoted my question on my second account

Comment: capturing event of the socket status change is about as real time as it gets. just set up your handlers accordingly and update the header at it happens